# R GGplot - Add additional tick-mark text on X axis in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df that looks like this:

```
students    test_number grade   date    Annotation
Jack    1   81.50107086 1/12/20 Math
Jack    2   95.44902345 1/13/20 Math
Jack    3   97.06091615 1/14/20 Math
Jack    4   95.27667508 1/15/20 Math
Jill    1   92.49229    2/15/20 Math
Jill    2   87.8457308  2/16/20 Math
Jill    3   85.4860858  2/17/20 Math
Jill    4   86.69897954 2/18/20 Math
Jake    1   88.35111817 1/11/20 Math
Jake    2   93.78062799 1/12/20 Math
Jake    3   95.69871618 1/13/20 Math
Jake    4   85.58356608 1/14/20 Math
Phill   1   93.46926154 1/12/20 Math
Phill   2   96.20396083 1/13/20 Math
Phill   3   87.70421535 1/14/20 Math
Phill   4   81.49549922 1/15/20 Math
```

And I am looping through each student to make a linegraph per test (example data has only 'math', but there are 3 tests on the same date) with x-axis being test-number as follows:

```
plot_list = list()
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  p = ggplot(all_students[all_students$students==var,], aes(x=test_number, y=grade, group=Annotation)) +
    geom_line()+           
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(var) +
    scale_shape(guide = FALSE) +
    xlab("Test Date + Number")
  plot_list[[var]] = p
}
pdf("all_students.pdf")
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  print(plot_list[[var]])
}
dev.off()
```

But I want the X axis to include the date as well as the test number. Right now it's only including the test number.

I've tried adding:

```
geom_text(aes(x=test_number, label=date))
```

but that adds dates -on- the plot instead of on the X axis.
Also tried:

```
    scale_x_discrete(labels= all_students$date)
```

but that adds the first observed dates as the X axis tick marks for all students (ie all plots have the same dates as X axis)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try join `test_number` with `date` first.

```
all_students <- all_students %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(idx = paste0(c(date, test_number), collapse = " - "))
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  p = ggplot(all_students[all_students$students==var,], aes(x=idx, y=grade, group=Annotation)) +
    geom_line()+           
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(var) +
    scale_shape(guide = FALSE) +
    xlab("Test Date + Number")
  plot_list[[var]] = p
}
plot_list$Jack
```

[image]

Also, if you want date and test number in different line,

```
all_students <- all_students %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(idx = paste0(c(date, test_number), collapse = "\n"))
```

[image]